# Discount rates, Formulas

Tags: math, mat

for example, I have 1 computer with a discount, the price of this computer is $ 450 with a 10% discount, I want to know the real price of it,
I want to learn this both over 10% and as 10% money.

```
Computer 10% off Price = 450$
Computer $10 off Price = 490$

$net_total = 450;
$discount_value = 10; < percent or amount
$gross_price =  ?;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, let's solve the equations:

```
Computer 10% off Price = 450$
Computer $10 off Price = 490$
```

Which can be written as (let `x` be the initial price of the computer)

```
x - x * 10 / 100 = 450  # initial price - x without 10 % from x - x * 10% / 100%
x - 10 = 490            # just 10$ off
```

Or

```
0.9 * x = 450
x = 500
```

Finally

```
x = 450 / 0.9 = 500
x = 500
```

So from both equations we have that the initial computer's price is `500$`

**Edit:** in general case,

if `$discount_value` stands for *per cent* (i.e. `$discount_value = 10` means `10%` discount) then

```
 $gross_price = $net_total * 100.0 / (100.0 - $discount_value)
```

if `$discount_value` stands for *money* (i.e. `$discount_value = 10` means `10$` discount), then

```
 $gross_price = $net_total + $discount_value
```

Comment: Updated the question, could you please edit it?

Comment: When I do as you say, the result is wrong.

Comment: `const x = (item.net_total -item.net_total*item.discount_value/100);`
Finally 405 :s

Comment: @lidersin: in order to find *initial price* (?) `x` you should not *subtract*, but *add*: `initial = net + off`

Comment: teacher are you there

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69941237/find-the-real-price-at-the-percentage-applied-price) **can you help me?**